# How to configure eclipse EE to use the external maven (Windows 7)

Tags: maven

New to maven. When I run this command i get access denied error? any help? I am trying to configure maven to run with eclipse. Let me know if you need more information.

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace=<c:\temp\eclipse\workspace>eclipse:add-mvn-repo

Path:
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bi
n\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\

C:\Temp\eclipse\workspace>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T09:51:4
2-04:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
C:\Temp\eclipse\workspace>cd\Temp\eclipse\workspace

**C:\Temp\eclipse\workspace>mvn -Declipse.workspace=<C:\Temp\eclipse\workspace> eclipse:add-maven-repo
Access is denied.
C:\Temp\eclipse\workspace>**
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Configuring Maven to run within Eclipse.

1. Eclipse has an embedded version of Maven which you can use. Assuming that you want to use Maven within Eclipse and outside of it,  download Maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi, extract it and set the **M2_HOME** environment variable such that it points to your local Maven installation directory.
2. Set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable so that it points to the JDK which you want to use.
3. Append **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** and **%M2_HOME%\bin** to the Path so that the jdk and mvn executables can be executed from anywhere.
4. Now open an Eclipse Workspace and go to *Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations*. If you want to use your standalone installation instead of using the embedded one, you can change it here.
5. If you have a specific Maven settings file which you want to use, then dump that settings.xml file under the .m2 folder of your User home directory.
6. Once this is done, you can easily use Maven from within eclipse.(*File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects*) or create a new one (*File > New > Maven > Maven Project*). Once you have a project in your workspace, you can run different Maven goals on it by right clicking on the Project and selecting what you want from the *Run As* option.

Comment: I am not able to get here -> ` Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations.` as my eclipse installation didn't come with maven support.

Comment: If you don't have m2e you can install it based on the instructions here http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/