# Using MAVEN_OPTS from Eclipse.in unit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing

I am using Eclipse Neon to edit my Maven project and define several environment variable in my .mavenrc file via the MAVEN_OPTS variable.  I use the maven-surefire plugin to run unit tests in Maven.  But when I run my unit tests in Eclipse, Eclipse runs the unit tests directly without using Maven; thus the environment variables are not set.  Is there any way to force Eclipse to use the environment variables I set in MAVEN_OPTS?  I don't want to have to set them in two places.

Comment: what environment variable are you setting, please share in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using eclipse junit plugin which is a part of eclipse [java development tools](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/). As mavenrc allows you to define environment variable for maven command, there is no way to read them through build in junit plugin. However, you could run the tests through [maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html). Remember to use [external maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463586/how-to-configure-eclipse-ee-to-use-the-external-maven-windows-7).

Some other ways of running inside eclipse junit plugin are

1. Maintain these variable as pom properties. In this way, every developer can have a their own environment specific values in settings.xml
2. Based on point 1, you either generate a java file which sets them as parameter. In this way your test class will depend on this generated file OR keep them in properties file and use resource filtering. Your test base would then read these properties.

Comment: There are a few problems with this:
1) This allows me to run all the unit tests for the project, but not to restrict it to a given unit test file or an individual test.  If I right-click on a Java file or a test method I don't see "debug as maven".
2) Even if I do debug at the project level, the debugger skips all my breakpoints.

Comment: You can run single test using maven sure fire plugin.  See http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html. Also you can debug the tests using http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html