# Build is getting success in Command prompt but not in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, maven

Trying to build a Java Spring project using Maven 3.6.1

Build is getting success in command prompt but the same is failed in eclipse

In eclipse getting this below exception :

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE:generateTests (default-generateTests) on project abcd-web: The plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE requires Maven version 3.2.5 -> [Help 1]

Comment: You're using eclipse's embedded maven. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463586/how-to-configure-eclipse-ee-to-use-the-external-maven-windows-7)

Comment: How can i change it to installed Maven if eclipse has embedded Maven

Comment: I added a link to my previous comment.

Comment: yes Thanks but i have mapped already with setting.xml

Comment: So can you confirm you specifically performed step 4 of the first answer at that link?