# Why is Eclipse hitting an NPE updating my Maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to split a maven project into submodules. It builds fine on the command-line, but when imported into eclipse I get the following error after a while, and then I'm forced to reimport the project.

The project struture is

- my-app

  - my-legacy-app
  - my-app-shared

It appears that eclipse is hitting an NPE when determining paths when updating the maven project. Where do I go from here to resolve this?

```
2020-10-20 15:23:12,368 [Worker-13: Updating maven profiles] WARN  o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractLifecycleMapping - Could not update project my-legacy-app configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.getProjectRelativePath(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:788) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.getOtherResourceFolders(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:535) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.overlapsWithOtherResourceFolder(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.addResourceDirs(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:475) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.addProjectSourceFolders(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:156) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$2(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:511) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:505) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:443) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1370) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:343) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core.internal.management.ProfileManager.updateActiveProfiles(ProfileManager.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui.internal.actions.ProfileSelectionHandler$UpdateProfilesJob.runInWorkspace(ProfileSelectionHandler.java:320) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Maybe try to configure eclipse to use maven from your machine instead of the embedded one. See it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468277/460557

Comment: Please show the entire log starting with `!SESSION` and tell the version of m2e (make sure that Eclipse with m2e is up-to-date).

Comment: @JorgeCampos This would have no effect here.

Comment: @howlger I've uploaded a log starting with !SESSION that covers yesterday and today here https://gist.github.com/OneGeek/d4aa047ca03820d946c86d87f0c2b61e   

m2e version info from Eclipse installation details is:
m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.16.1.20200710-1008 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - m2e

Comment: If you can reproduce it with the current Eclipse without additional plugins, create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, find out by which additional plugin it is caused.

Comment: @howlger I debugged Eclipse and it turns out it was m2e failing to detect a problem with the POM and surface an error with actionable context, not any other plugin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up grabbing the source code to m2e and debugging my Eclipse instance, putting a breakpoint on `AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.getProjectRelativePath()` to directly examine the source of the NPE.

The cause ended up being a missing `<directory>...</directory>` element within a `<resource>...</resource>` element. I didn't find it earlier because m2e/Eclipse didn't surface any context for the error.

Comment: Please make sure that this has been [reported to m2e](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e).